# php getting substring from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, url

I have the next URL: `http://domen.com/aaa/bbb/ccc`.
How can I get the string after `http://domen.com/`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$sub = substr($string, 0, 10);
```

But if you actually want to parse the URL (that is, you want it to work with all URLs), use parse_url. For "http://domen.com/aaa/bbb/ccc", it would give you an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => domen.com
    [user] => 
    [pass] => 
    [path] => /aaa/bbb/ccc
    [query] => 
    [fragment] => 
)
```

You could then compile this into the original url (to get http://domen.com/):

```
$output = $url['scheme'] . "://" . $url['host'] . $url['path'];
```

assuming $url contains the parse_url results.

Comment: The `substr` example would be more appropriate to this question if it were of the `substr($string, 17)` variety. But regardless, `parse_url` should be used if applicable.

Comment: ^ I didn't count the characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php).

Your code will be something like:

```
$s = "http://domen.com/aaa/bbb/ccc";
$vals = split("http://domen.com/", $s);
// $v will contain aaa/bbb/ccc
$v = $vals[1];
```

Comment: PHP doesn't support array dereferencing, so `split(...)[0]` won't work.  You'd need to store the result in a variable and then access the member...

Answer (score 2):

[parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php Might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the string and the "http://domen.com/" part is fixed:

```
$url = 'http://domen.com/aaa/bbb/ccc';
$str = str_replace('http://domen.com/','',$url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex for example like the function preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/^.*?\w\//', '', $url)
```